# Testing for alignment with floating point

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, dot-product

This is for a physics engine:

When an object collides over a slope, its speed will adjust accordingly to be parallel to said slope.

To check if an object is moving towards or away from the slope, I use a dot product between the slope's normal and the velocity of the object.

The problem arises due to floating point math. Sometimes, the velocity of the object is parallel to the slope, but not -perfectly- parallel, causing it to be detected as a collision.

In most cases, this is incorrect, as the velocity will constantly be readjusted to be parallel, checked again and be detected once more.

**Is there any way to avoid this behavior without having to store extra variables?**

(I could easily add a copy of the slope to check it was recently hit, but this would result in a lot more checks for every single object)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a minimum deviation from the slope that leads to a collision detection check. i.e. if the slopes are verry similar, don't check for a collision. e.g. a deviation by less than 0.01° should be seen as parallel.

Comment: That would be possible, however it would result in dividing the dot product by the length of the slope before doing the check. Otherwise longer slopes would have a different threshold than shorter ones. The fact that this adds a square root to the check is quite bad, as it's harder to compute.

Comment: You can divide the normal of the slope by the length of the slope once, then you do not have to redo the division over and over again. However, depending on the use case, this of course can have a significant effect on the performance.